# Figuring out whether a number is a Double in Java

Tags: java, typeof

I'm a Java newbie. I'm trying to figure out whether a number is a Double with something like this:

```
if ( typeof ( items.elementAt(1) )== Double ) {
       sum.add( i, items.elementAt(1));
}
```

Would appreciate if someone could tell me how to rearrange the syntax to make this work properly.

Comment: Is it just me, or is typeof(object) not actually real in C#?  I always thought it was typeof(type)...  `object o = new object();  Type t = typeof(o);` throws a compiler error saying `o is a variable but is used like a type`.  The name of this question is misguiding...

Comment: In c#, all objects have an `Object#GetType()` method, which returns a `Type`. That can then be used to compare with `typeof()`. In this case, it would be `items.elementAt(1).GetType() == typeof(double)`.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (items.elementAt(1) instanceof Double) {
   sum.add( i, items.elementAt(1));
}
```

Comment: +1. I'm also thinking you actually want to check `elementAt(0)`; majority of stuff in Java is zero-based.

Answer (score 18):

Since this is the first question from Google I'll add the JavaScript style `typeof` alternative here as well:

```
myObject.getClass().getName() // String
```

Answer (score 8):

Reflection is slower, but works for a situation when you want to know whether that is of type Dog or a Cat and not an instance of Animal. So you'd do something like:

```
if(null != items.elementAt(1) && items.elementAt(1).getClass().toString().equals("Cat"))
{
//do whatever with cat.. not any other instance of animal.. eg. hideClaws();
}
```

Not saying the answer above does not work, except the null checking part is necessary.

Another way to answer that is use generics and you are guaranteed to have Double as any element of items.

```
List<Double> items = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

Comment: Could you please people learn to put reasons for negative rating? I'm new in java too and I'd like to see what's wrong with this answer so I don't have to try it!

Comment: I would avoid comparing to a hard coded string, what if the class name changes, also instanceof exists so we use that.

Comment: @enrey What's the advantage of this over instanceof?

Comment: @CharlesShiller The advantage is late binding of the string "Cat".

Comment: +1 for `.getClass().toString()` because I can’t import the class due to one way dependency inejction. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression to achieve this task. Please refer the below code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter your content: ");
        String data = reader.readLine();            
        boolean b1 = Pattern.matches("^\\d+$", data);
        boolean b2 = Pattern.matches("[0-9a-zA-Z([+-]?\\d*\\.+\\d*)]*", data); 
        boolean b3 = Pattern.matches("^([+-]?\\d*\\.+\\d*)$", data);
        if(b1) {
            System.out.println("It is integer.");
        } else if(b2) {
            System.out.println("It is String. ");
        } else if(b3) {
            System.out.println("It is Float. ");
        }           
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TypeOF.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great example,  what is 'TypeOF' btw? in last line.