# Get text if component is jlabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have a LayeredPane2 with mant components such as jlabels, jbutton etc.
I want to loop in the components and if the component is a Jlabel, get it's text.
How can I do this? Here is my code so far:

```
   //search the components
   for (int j=0; j<jLayeredPane2.getComponents().length; j++){
     //if it is a jlabel
     if ("class javax.swing.JLabel".equals(jLayeredPane2.getComponent(j).getClass().toString())){
        //HOW DO I GET THE LABEL TEXT??
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the `instanceof` keyword, then a cast:

```
if(jLayeredPane2.getComponent(j) instanceof JLabel) {
    JLabel label = (JLabel)jLayeredPane2.getComponent(j);
    String text = label.getText();
    //...Then do whatever you want to do with said text.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [JLabel docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#getText%28%29), you can use the `getText()` method to retrieve the label text.

```
String labelText = ((JLabel) jLayeredPane2.getComponent(j)).getText();
```

To check if the component is a JLabel you can use the comparison

```
if (jLayeredPane2.getComponent(j) instanceof JLabel) { }
```

as was already suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1641622/3227787).

Your final code would be something like this:

```
if (jLayeredPane2.getComponent(j) instanceof JLabel) {
    Label label = (JLabel) jLayeredPane2.getComponent(j);
    String labelText = label.getText();
}
```

Comment: Nope - `jLayeredPane2.getComponent(j).getText()` will fail, since not every component provides a `getText()` method.

Comment: I forgot to add the casting.